# What is the next Step after applying for a CRBA --

Tags: immigration, citizenship, us-citizens, passport, social-security

I am trying to figure out what is the next step after getting completed with the CRBA for my daughter that was born abroad.
She was provided an American passport and currently resides in the United States.

I know i will need to get her a SSN -- Is there a particular form i will need to fill out for her?
Do i need to do any adjustment of Status ?

Comment: CRBA are available up to age 18. I infer the daughter is a small child. If she is approaching age 18 or has income of her own there are several other matters to attend to.

Comment: She might have citizenship from the place she was born. If one or both of the parents have non-US citizenship, she might inherit that citizenship. You may wish to investigate if any steps are needed to preserve the other citizenship.

Comment: Did your daughter enter the US with her US passport?  If not, how did she enter?  It doesn't much matter one way or the other; I'm just wondering why you're asking about "adjustment of status."

Answer (score 2):

To apply for an SSN, submit form [SS-5 Application for a Social Security Card](https://www.ssa.gov/forms/ss-5.pdf) on behalf of your daughter. The instructions on the form tell you how to fill it out and how to find out where to send the form.

There is no need for adjustment of status, since she is a US citizen and has the passport to prove it, so she has the right to stay in the US indefinitely.